# How can I make a chart with dates on the y axis Chart.js

Tags: javascript, php, chart.js

I have a collection of projects, each of which have a completion date. I am trying to display it on a horizontal bar graph such that the label is on the y-axis and the completion date is on the x-axis, as in this image:
[Target axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qT1yi.png). I am currently using Chart.js

The problem I am encountering is that Chart.js seems to be incapable of interpreting my data as dates - instead it evaluates it (for example, 2017-02-10 is interpreted as 2005). Based on the documentation at chartjs.org/docs/#scales-time-scale, I have tried to use Moment.js to parse my date strings into moments, but it can't render it.

My best guess is that, since it's a horizontal bar graph, my x-axis values are being treated like y-axis values, and the documentation states that the time scale is only supported on the x-axis.

Is there some workaround that would allow me to use dates as the data, so that it looks like this image, but with the axes from the first image? If not, is there another library I could use that does support this? I haven't found any examples of people using time scales on a horizontal graph, so I don't know if other libraries like CanvasJS can do it either.

[Goal data, but wrong x-axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q5Hb5.png)

Thanks.

Comment: Can you make a live example? Look at [this plunker example](https://jsfiddle.net/oe1r8kbw/) - you could probably fork it and change the values to match your data...

Comment: The example is backwards from what I need. Since I'm using a horizontal chart, even though my dates are on the x-axis, the x-axis is a function of the y. We are used to seeing y as a function of x, so the dates on my x-axis are actually like the y-axis. I tried switching x and y data in the live example and it got wonky.

Comment: Okay I am flagging this for closure: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working**?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See [how to create a minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I recommend you create an example like the plunker I mentioned earlier with a sample of your data.